# How to configure MySQL under Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I configured my Zend Framework virtualhost environment, but now my files cannot access the MySQL database. Getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.

Where should I configure my MySQL so that it matches my virtualhost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using `Zend_Db` and you have configured MySQL as you adapter in [Zend DB Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.5/en/zend.db.html)

Also, in your `application.ini` file under `configs` folder,

you must write:

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.dbname = "<your database name>"
resources.db.params.host = "<your host name>"
resources.db.params.username = "<mysql username>"
resources.db.params.password = "<mysql password>"
resources.db.params.charset  = "UTF8"
```

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: The reason I wrote about phpSettings is so that you can see errors effectively , if at all they come up!

Comment: always enforce connection charset or you may face problems in less expected moment: `resources.db.params.charset  = UTF8`

Comment: both links are broken

Comment: @bubakazouba Thank you for the heads up! Updated the links :)